# 16x2 LCD display not working with arduino or RaspPi

Tags: arduino, lcd

I have a 16x2 LCD display that I'm just trying to use for the first time. The model number is 1602D1 according to [this datasheet](http://www.taydaelectronics.com/datasheets/A-1748.pdf) from where I purchased it. I first tried attaching it to a Raspberry Pi using Adafruit's tutorial, which had the same pinouts as the LCD display I have. Now I've tried using an Arduino and I get the same results, which are shown in the picture below.

[image]

The LCD display never updates when I try to send text to it and only displays the blocks in the bottom row. Adjusting the 10k variable resistor doesn't seem to do anything. When I send data to the LCD, I notice it flickering slightly as if its updating, but no text is displayed.  I'm simply using the code from tutorials, nothing special.  Any ideas what I am doing wrong? Thanks.

For clarity because the picture might be misleading, here is how I have the pins hooked up:

LCD Pins:

- LCD 1 - Ground
- LCD 2 - 5V
- LCD 3 - 10k Variable resistor middle pin
- LCD 4 - Arduino 12
- LCD 5 - Ground
- LCD 6 - Arduino 11
- LCD 7 through 10 empty
- LCD 11 - Arduino 5
- LCD 12 - Arduino 4
- LCD 13 - Arduino 3
- LCD 14 - Arduino 2
- LCD 15 - 5V
- LCD 16 - Ground

Variable resistor:

- Left - 5V
- Middle pin - LCD pin 3
- Right - Ground

Comment: Its not entirely clear from your pic, but it looks as though you've got pin 4 of your LCD tied to ground (through the 2 green wires) as well as over to your arduino.

Comment: No, I have pin 5 tied to ground. Pin 4 goes to arduino pin 12. I'll edit my question to clarify.

Comment: That's actually the top row, and the display hasn't been initialized properly.

Comment: The LCD by default is in the 8-bit mode. Did you send the proper init sequence to it to use the 4-bit mode? It's probably a matter of calling the right init from the library.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're reading the pins upside down.

Comment: Hey you're right. Doh! It works great now. Good thing I didn't fry anything. I should be more careful next time.